# Maven compiled class with -f command not in war file

Tags: maven, compilation

In my project I have several `pom.xml` files. For a module, I must get the war file with -f command like this

```
mvn clean install -f pom-example.xml
```

But when I run this command, only  a few classes don't get added to the war file.

If I run

```
mvn clean install
```

I see that the classes are there in the war file.

What is the problem? Why are these compiled classes not in the war file when I run `-f` command?

Comment: `-f `option is used to specify the pom file name. If your pom file is having name other than `pom.xml` then use `-f` to specify the pom file name.

Answer (score 1):

This uses pom-example.xml

```
mvn clean install -f pom-example.xml
```

This uses pom.xml

```
mvn clean install
```

I think it's confusing have 2 pom files in the same directory, if you want different behavior I would use profiles and one pom see http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html